# Anyway to filter access records containing an '#'?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database that is being used for a website.  In the DB there is a field for image file names that is used to display images on the site.  In some case the person responsible for gathering the images started using the # character in the image file names when saving them and this is causing the images not show on the website.

Is there anyway to filter out just the records where the image field contains the '#' character?

Everything I've tried has Access treating it like a wildcard and picking up any number.

Comment: Gord Thompson has posted an amazing way: `WHERE [ImageFileField] LIKE 
'*[#]*' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can select rows which have `#` contained in your *image_file_name* field by checking whether the field is `LIKE '*[#]*'`

However, since you want to *filter out* those rows, target the inverse of that pattern match ... `NOT LIKE '*[#]*'`

A query like this would work within an Access session with default settings:

```sql
SELECT y.*
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.image_file_name Not Like '*[#]*';
```

However, since you're using the Access db to feed a website, you may be using ADO/OleDb to connect to the db file.  If that is the case, use `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard character:

```sql
WHERE y.image_file_name Not Like '%[#]%';
```

Or you could use `Alike` instead of `Like`.  In that situation, the wildcard should always be `%` and the query will work correctly whether you're running it from within or outside of Access:

```sql
WHERE y.image_file_name Not ALike '%[#]%';
```

A totally different approach is to use `InStr` to find the position of `#` within *image_file_name* and select the rows where `InStr` returns zero:

```sql
SELECT y.*
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE InStr(1, y.image_file_name, '#') = 0;
```

If you also want rows where *image_file_name* is Null, you can add that condition to the `WHERE` clause with `OR`.